# Android requestLocationUpdates and time needed to get a gps fix

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am using the requestLocationUpdates method of [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to get GPS location updates. I am using a minTime parameter of 60000 to indicate that I'd like a location update every minute - I don't care about minDistance (I use a value of 0 as minDistance).

If I can understand correctly the android documentation, my LocationListener will be executed every minute to receive the current location. This is what happens with the emulator.

However, I couldn't understand what would happen between executions: Will the GPS be turned off every time ? And If the GPS is turned off, what will happen with the time needed to get a GPS fix (that time could be more than one minute) ? Will I get updates every 1 minute + (time neede to get the GPS fix) ?

Unfortunately the emulator cannot help me with these problems and I do not have an Android device in my hands right now, so If anybody has experience with this stuff help me !

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not specified, because that is implementation-specific.

Answer (score 1):

The latest GPS chipsets can usually get a lock in well under a minute, often less than 20 seconds, so you should be fine.